# Multiple Image upload using cloudinary

Tags: node.js, graphql, cloudinary, prisma

when I tried to upload multiple images at same time it uploads the same image (an image which one was selected first) twice.

I use `{multiple:1}` but still it doesn't work.

```
const uploadToCloudinary = filename =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const publicId = randomize("0", 5);
    // cloudinary.uploader.image_upload_tag(filename, { html: { multiple: 1 } });
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(
      filename,
      {
        html: { multiple: 1 },
        tags: "basic_sample",
        public_id: publicId,
        folder: "vizard",
        eager: [
          {
            width: 200,
            crop: "fit"
          },
          { width: 10, crop: "fit" }
        ]
      },
      (err, image) => {
        if (err) console.warn(err);
        return resolve({
          original: image && image.url,
          w200: image && image.eager[0].url,
          placeholder: image.eager[1].url,
          publicId: image.public_id
        });
      }
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [upload](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) method of the [Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference) does not support a field called `html` and is used to upload files directly rather than create an input field where those can be selected.

What you're probably looking for is the [image_upload_tag](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload#direct_upload_file_tag) or the jQuery direct upload functionality for multiple files - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_and_video_upload#upload_multiple_images